# How to read large files (Excel) in NodeJS without pausing UI

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, exceljs

I'm currently using [ExcelJS](https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs) to read large Excel files (10,000+ lines) into a NodeJS/Angular/Electron app. It reads the smaller files just fine, but the larger files take anywhere from 3.9 to 5 seconds to read, and during that time, the CSS doesn't update at all.

I'm currently using async/await to load the files, as I thought that would allow other operations to happen while waiting on the file load, as I thought I/O operations in Node had their own thread. I also read that CPU intensive tasks block all other Node processes.

This is the code that currently loads the workbook:

```
async openWorkbook(filename: string) {
    this.loading = true;
    const workbook = new Workbook();
    const promise = workbook.xlsx.readFile(this.path + '/sheets/' + filename)
      .then(() => {
        // use workbook
        workbook.getWorksheet(1).name = workbook.getWorksheet(1).name.slice(0, 31);
        const excelFile: ExcelFile = { workbook: workbook, filename: filename };
        this.wbSource.next(excelFile);
      });

    const read = await promise;
  }
```

This code works the same as the callback implementation, they both block the app's CSS. How would I go about reading a file (or do any CPU intensive task) without blocking the UI?

Comment: Isn't this an ideal candidate for serviceworkers? or web workers? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Comment: Create a timer using setInterval to run at regular intervals, read N rows at a time, do something with them then exit the timer and allow it to run again, when all rows have been read clean up by stopping the timer and closing the open workbook.

Comment: @SPlatten - ouch! that is doing it the hard way.

Comment: @Deckerz I thought I read somewhere that you should avoid using web/service workers for I/O tasks?

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce, whats hard about it?

Comment: @SPlatten it's not that it's necessarily *hard* it's just completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce., suggest an alternative then?

Comment: @SPlatten - the correct way to do this is to use a worker. That's already been suggested.

Comment: By workers you mean threads?  Thats really no different from using a timer except probably more resource hungry.

Comment: For simplicity you could use this [`Thread`](https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/683d5ae429448adfa6d6e7fb30de39b2) function if you want, I wrote this to solve a similar problem where I didn't want to maintain a whole-nother file to handle one task.

Comment: @SPlatten - timers (on the ui thread) run on a the same thread as the ui. Using a timer is absolutely **not** the same thing as using a worker. The timer needs to be stopped and resumed while a worker does not.

Comment: Honestly a timer is probably more resource intensive as it has to constantly start and stop IO. Rather than doing it in one go.

Comment: A thread is started and runs in a loop until its done, if you don't sleep for a while then it eats up CPU resources, a timer is similar once its running in that it's called, does something then goes to sleep until its needed again, really no difference.

Comment: @SPlatten - your understanding of timer functions is fundamentally wrong. timers do not in any way shape or form create a new thread. Consider scope, you can write a setTimeout function that refers to a global variable. If a timer was a separate thread the global variables wouldn't be accessible.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce., I never said that timers were threads, but the way they run and occupy time is similar to a thread.  I develop multi-thread applications all the time, so I'm quite aware of how they work.

Comment: @SPlatten, i'm sorry my friend but what you're saying is just incorrect. i'm not trying to insult you but if you're using timers you are not creating multi-threaded apps. javascript executes statements in a queue. using a timer takes one statement and moves it back further in the queue so it can be executed later, but it is still only executing one statement at a time. opening a new thread allows the computer to execute multiple statements simultaneously (multiple queues). stop for a second. instead of trying to win an argument here, try to learn something.

Comment: that said, the solution you mentioned is certainly very clever. being able to think like that is what makes programmers great. you just misunderstood how the language works. it's nothing to be offended by.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing i would do in this case is preventing memory overhead by not "opening" large files at all.

So something like this should work:

```
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
stream.pipe(workbook.xlsx.createInputStream());
```

and as those [chunks](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) block the cycle for a minor amount of time you can use this even in the javascript event loop ;)

Comment: I think streams are probably the way to go, but I keep getting an Error: Argument of type 'Writable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'WritableStream'

Comment: Wow how annoying - quick workaround should be stream.on('data', (chunk)=>excelstream.write(chunk)) but i will check source on github

Comment: @MusicDev Just to confirm before i run into a wall - its not a typescript error?

Comment: Sorry about the wait, it's totally a TypeScript problem. ExcelJS changed the return type of getInputStream a while back: 
https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/575

Comment: @MusicDev - i am sorry - my answer is nonsense as exceljs actually uses streams but somehow blocks until the stream finished ... https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/blob/3c5ebd2a816dbb67d9a73c8716756d5530224792/lib/xlsx/xlsx.js#L55

Comment: One thing I notice is that loading animations are working, but now quite choppy. I think I'll stick with this for now. Thank you!

Comment: I was trying this answer but looks like createInputStream has been deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is a single threaded language. If one of your task is taking long to complete, other tasks like rendering will be blocked. I can't write complete code for you but Web Worker seems a perfect solution for what you're trying to do. (Which people have already suggested in comments)

You can refer:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers

Additionally, also check out https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/comlink which is a wrapper around the Web Worker APIs. It'll make it easier for you to migrate existing code to worker with less hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to leave my solution here using my [Thread](https://gist.github.com/Pamblam/683d5ae429448adfa6d6e7fb30de39b2) function from the comments.

```js
async openWorkbook(filename: string) {
  this.loading = true;

  var path = this.path + '/sheets/' + filename;
  const excelFile = await Thread(path, function(path, exit) {

    // You'll need to import excel again since it's a new thread
    import Excel from 'exceljs';

    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.xlsx.readFile(path).then(() => {
      workbook.getWorksheet(1).name = workbook.getWorksheet(1).name.slice(0, 31);
      const excelFile: ExcelFile = {
        workbook: workbook,
        filename: filename
      };
      exit(excelFile);
    });
  });

  this.wbSource.next(excelFile);

}
```